# What's wrong with my XCOPY line?

Tags: windows-7, xcopy

I'm trying to write a batch file that will copy all new files from a source to a destination without prompting (it will be running on a server). This script will not copy files that already exist in the destination.

To do this I've set a source, destination and the /Y flag to ignore any prompting about copying files that already exist.

My command is:

```
xcopy \\source \\destination /Y
```

However I'm receiving the error:

> "Invalid Number of Parameters"

and don't understand why.

Comment: does `\\source` contains files, directories or both?

Comment: Nope, I had spaces in my source/destination and forgot to encapsulate them in quotes!

Comment: and that's why we say post the *exact* command.

Comment: It's for work - so always anonymised. Most likely not covered by a non-confidentiality but there is one in place so it always pays to be cautious when internal auditors love to pounce on any and everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the exact command you're entering, all I can tell you is that the most common reason for this is that one or both of the paths you're specifying includes spaces.  Try enclosing the source and destination paths in double quotes ("path").